# cases for gcc to ignore register declaration?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

K&R says

> compilers are free to ignore the advice (register declaration).

In what cases, gcc would ignore if I define `register int x = 4;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally implementation-dependent.

In general, you should trust the compiler to put variables to register and not define them yourself.

> #### C99 6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers
>
> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier `register`
>   suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

Plus, C++11 has deprecated the use of the `register` keyword as a storage-class-specifier, maybe sometime in the future C will do the same.

Comment: I hope the C committee won't deprecate `register`, Jens Gustedt has some good suggestions for it: http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/named-constants/ Also the C11 standard refers to `register` in at least one place where the C99 standard didn't: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm

Answer (score 2):

By declaring a variable as `‘register’`, we are only requesting (not forcing) the compiler to store variable a in CPU register. Compiler will decide where to store the variable.

If you have declared more variables as `register`, then few of them might get into the CPU register as the CPU registers are limited. That is again implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If we refer to the C99 draft standard we see that this is implementation defined, section `6.7.1` *Storage-class specifiers* paragraph *4* says:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier register
>   suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective **is implementation-defined**.

[This thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00098.html) from `gcc` mailing list seems to indicate if you follow the thread a bit that `register` has been ignored for a while except in the case that you do not use optimization(*using -O0*).

Note that using `register` does have another impact in that it prevents the use of address operator(`&`).